# Send And Recieve SNMP traps and create MIB file for NAS device

Tags: python, c, snmp, pysnmp, snmptrapd

I am planning to develop a feature of generating snmp traps and to send them.

And also I want to receive them which I sent.

For that I need to create MIB file as well.

I know that snmp traps can be received based on MIB file.

I got lot of content on web but got confused where to start of developing.

Could you please help me out...

1) How to generate and send SNMP traps?

2) How to create MIB file ?

3) How to receive snmp traps generated?

**Requirement:** If I set snmp receiver's(some linux host) IP at snmp sender(NAS box)...snmp receiver should receive the traps from sender?

Note: Mostly I want to use python and C language to fulfill it.

Thanks in advance,
NagaPavan

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming question

Answer (score 2):

You can send and receive SNMP notifications using one of numerous tools in existence. In case of C that might be Net-SNMP, if it's Python you may consider playing with pysnmp.

MIB is not strictly required for SNMP notifications to work. Use of MIB helps automating notification build and process, but for specific types of notifications that can be done by hand e.g. without MIB.

To start with, [these snippets](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/agent/ntforg/common-notifications.html) will generate SNMP notifications, while [these scripts](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/v3arch/asyncore/contents.html) will receive them.

I'd advise you reading some more on SNMP to get better understanding of the technology. It is not simple, despite its name. ;)